# Double-indexed dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to be able to store and look up values in a dictionary based on two integer values.

So when I look up a value I want to use the keys `read_length` and `min_size` to access the element, like so:

```
number_of_read_lengths[read_length][min_size]
```

I know I can create nested dictionaries, but that is a slight hassle.

Is there a simple way of doing what I want to do?

Comment: See promanows answer for a discussion of some of the limitations of the accepted reply.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can use any immutable and hashable object as key, including tuples

```py
number_of_read_lengths = {}    
number_of_read_lengths[14,3] = "Your value"
```

Comment: @TheUnfunCat Note that this is possible because tuples in Python are  hashable. They are also immutable but this is not a requirement to be a `dict` key. (though they should be immutable too!)

Comment: @JBernardo that is much better looking =)

Comment: @TheUnfunCat 1,2 is a valid tuple, the parens are only required for the empty tuple

Comment: Is order of the indexes are important?

Comment: Yes, @alper, because `assert (14,3) != (3,14)`.

Answer (score 4):

Using tuples could be quite annoying -- you got to remember to place the tuple during indexing.

I would recommend a nested dict, but a `defaultdict`, like so:

```
from collections import defaultdict

number_of_read_lengths = defaultdict(dict)

number_of_read_lengths[1][2] = 3

print(number_of_read_lengths)
```

This code would give:

```
defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, {1: {2: 3}})
```

This way, any non-existing element in the `number_of_read_lengths` dict will be created as a dict when accessing or setting it. Simple and effective.

More info on `defaultdict`: http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict
There are also examples: http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples

Comment: Thanks, UV, but I already used eakron's suggestion. But nice to know. What do you mean by "remember to place the tuple during indexing"?

Comment: By indexing [(1, 2)] or [1, 2] - not what you usually use for flat dict indexing. There is also one more problem with tuples, they are immutable... So changing a value would require deletion and re-addition.

Answer (score 3):

You could try to use tuples as keys:

```
number_of_read_lengths[(read_length, min_size)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to expand a bit more from the comment I made:

A `dict` key *must* be hashable, which a simple tuple is. However, a tuple that contains unhashable values such as lists, is not hashable (even though it is immutable!) and therefore cannot be used as `dict` key:

```
>>> bad = ([12],[32])
# still immutable
>>> bad[1] = [21]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

# but not hashable!
>>> d = {}
>>> d[bad] = 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

You can even have mutable *and* hashable objects as `dict` keys, but it's not really useful and should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to define double indexed dictionaries. For me it is easier to visualize this one rather than other methods.

```
dict_dict_v2 = {}
dict_dict_v2.setdefault(2, {})
dict_dict_v2.setdefault(3, {})
dict_dict_v2[2]['1.1.1.1'] = {}
dict_dict_v2[2]['1.0.1.0'] = {}
dict_dict_v2[3]['1.1.1.1'] = "double"
dict_dict_v2[3]['1.0.1.0'] = 12    

dict_dict_v2[2]['1.1.1.1']['mac']=1111
dict_dict_v2[2]['1.1.1.1']['id']=1111

dict_dict_v2[2]['1.0.1.0']['id']=1010

print str(dict_dict_v2)
"""output: 
{1: {'1.0.0.0': {'mac': 1010, 'id': 1000}, '1.1.1.1': {'mac': 1111}}, 
 2: {'1.1.1.1': {'mac': 1111, 'id': 1111}, '1.0.1.0': {'id': 1010}}, 
 3: {'1.1.1.1': 'double', '1.0.1.0': 12}}
"""
```

You could use the dict basic functions as below:

```
print "len-> "+str(len(dict_dict_v2[2]))
print "keys-> "+str(dict_dict_v2[2].keys())
print "values-> "+str(dict_dict_v2[2].values())
"""output: 
len-> 2
keys-> ['1.1.1.1', '1.0.1.0']
values-> [{'mac': 1111, 'id': 1111}, {'id': 1010}]
"""
print "len for 1.1.1.1-> "+str(len(dict_dict_v2[2]['1.1.1.1']))
print "keys for 1.1.1.1-> "+str(dict_dict_v2[2]['1.1.1.1'].keys())
print "values for 1.1.1.1-> "+str(dict_dict_v2[2]['1.1.1.1'].values())
"""output: 
len for 1.1.1.1-> 2
keys for 1.1.1.1-> ['mac', 'id']
values for 1.1.1.1-> [1111, 1111]
"""
```